typescript settimeout in nested recursive function
I am trying to put settimeout in recursive function call where main function called recursively and subfunction also called recursively. Here is my code i am trying.
this.myArray = Array(2).fill(undefined);
  StartFunction(len: number) {
    console.info('in StartFunction ', len);
    this.SubFunction_1(len);
    this.SubFunction_2(len);    
    if (len > 0) {
      this.myArray.pop();
      this.StartFunction(this.myArray.length);
    }
  }
  SubFunction_1(input: number) {
    console.warn('in SubFunction_1 ', input);
  }
  async SubFunction_2(input: number) {
    console.error('in SubFunction_2 ', input);
    if (input > 0) {
      input--;
      //     const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.SubFunction_2(input);
        //         resolve('getData completed ' + input);
      }, 1000);
      //       // const data = await promise;
      //       // console.log(data);
    }
  }

I want to execute functions in order and wait for SubFunction_2 to complete before proceeding further. Also created stackblitz for the same
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v7ycuk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
Tried few things (commented) but could not achieve this. Suggestions ?

All you need is async and await it from the first call.
I could provide the code in the answer section if you need that

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep?noredirect=1&lq=1 for how to write an async sleep() function that you can await.

Like other commenters have mentioned, you need to use await to achieve your goal. I'll also note that the code you've posted here doesn't appear to be valid javascript, but appears to be using some typescript syntax instead. You should update your tags accordingly

@AustinDuling . My bad. i have changed the tag. I have tried await also but i think not using in right place or right way

Why have you put code in comments? It looks like you already used await there, but then went back to. ... not using it. You don't want to use await? If you do want to use await, then please only provide the code with await so we can see where you went wrong with it.

Your sub functions should return promises, try the following:
async SubFunction_2(input: number) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.error('in SubFunction_2 ', input);
        if (input > 0) {
            input--;
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.SubFunction_2(input).then(resolve).catch(reject);
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            resolve('function completed');
        }
    });
}

Edit to call from the function you provided:
StartFunction(len: number) {
    console.info('in StartFunction ', len);
    this.SubFunction_1(len);
    this.SubFunction_2(len).then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      if (len > 0) {
        this.myArray.pop();
        this.StartFunction(this.myArray.length);
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
  }


Thanks @Austin Duling. Thanks a million :-) . This is exactly how i want to run the code.
